# Chain Puzzle: Tabletop Games #02 – Pictionary

Tags: visual

<sub>This is the second [Chain Puzzle](//puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7018) in the [Tabletop Games](/search?q=title%3A%22chain+puzzle%22+title%3A%22tabletop+games%22+is%3Aquestion) series, in which all puzzles are themed around board games, card games, tile games, and the like. The answer to this puzzle is a thematic word or phrase. The solver whose answer is awarded the green checkmark has first refusal on the opportunity to create the next puzzle in the series, which must somehow incorporate the answer to this puzzle somewhere within its construction. The solver is under no *obligation* to create the next puzzle: in the event that he or she does not wish to take that opportunity, I may accept the offer of a willing substitute setter or choose to continue the chain myself.</sub>

[The game of Pictionary](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pictionary) requires a player to draw a word or phrase he's secretly given, and his teammates to guess the word. Classically, the words and phrases come in categories like

- **P: person, place, or animal** — this can be a proper noun or just a noun
- **O: object** — a thing
- **A: action** — something to do
- **D: difficult** — this can be anything at all, but is usually more difficult

Here were my team's clues, and what the sketcher first drew for each. See if you can find the words! As in the game, if you don't get the answer after some time, I'll show you what the sketcher drew next.

#### 1. P

[image]

#### 2. O

[image]

#### 3. A

[image]

#### 4. D

[image]

> [image]

#### 5. P

[image]

#### 6. O

[image]

#### 7. A

[image]

#### 8. D

[image]

#### 9. P

[image]

> [image]

#### 10. O

[image]

#### 11. A

[image]

#### 12. D

[image]

> [image]

#### 13. P

[image]

#### 14. O

[image]

#### 15. A

[image]

#### 16. D

[image]

#### 17. P

[image]

#### 18. O

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>*A so-very-nearly-complete answer - just #9 left to identify, but final answer found...*</sub>

---

The answer to the puzzle is:

> **[MORNINGTON CRESCENT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent_(game))**

To reach this, we need to solve the eighteen Pictionary clues and then:

> take the first letter of each answer.

Clues resolve as follows (credit to solvers in discussions in the dedicated Chain Puzzle [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115326/chain-puzzles)):

> 1. **M**ICKEY MOUSE (shape of ears) *(@Stiv)*
>  2. **O**RANGE JUICE *(@Stiv)*
>  3. **R**UN *(@Stiv)*
>  4. **N**EANDERTHAL (note the differences in skull shape) *(@AlanHoover)*
>  5. **I**STANBUL (position marked on a map of Turkey) *(@Stiv)*
>  6. **N**EST *(@Stiv)*
>  7. **G**ROW *(@Stiv)*
>  8. **T**HAMES (depicted on a map of the UK) *(@Stiv)*
>  9. **O** - ???
>  10. **N**UNCHUCKS *(@Braegh)*
>  11. **C**RY *(@LukasRotter)*
>  12. **R**ASTAFARIAN *(@AlanHoover)*
>  13. **E**STONIA (position marked on a map of Europe) *(@Stiv)*
>  14. **S**POON *(@Stiv)*
>  15. **C**APTURE (chess move) *(@Braegh)*
>  16. **E**XCALIBUR (the 'sword in the stone') *(@LukasRotter)*
>  17. [**N**YAN CAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyan_Cat) *(@Braegh)*
>  18. **T**ABLET (medicinal pill) *(@Stiv)*

Comment: 12 might be rot13(ebpxrg)?

Comment: @athin, not my intention, I'm afraid.

Comment: Could 4 be Narcissus?

Comment: 12 is marking a female person from East Africa (near Somalia, Kenya or Ethiopia). If working backwards from R, googling suggests Ruth Negga?

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu Narcissus was the first guess in chat (and we thought it was right!) but OP said wrong.

Comment: 12 is I think Refugee

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu I guessed that in a previous edit too, but no dice :) Good to know someone else thinks on the same line as me!

Comment: 12 is Repatriate?

Comment: @Pumesies, no, sorry.

Comment: I've added hints to the question for the remaining sketches.

Comment: is 4 Neanderthal?  12 Ras Tafari?

Comment: 9 Ophelia (the face that launched a thousand ships)

Comment: @AlanHoover I like your suggestions for 4 and 12 - I'm sure msh210 can confirm if they're correct. 9, I'm still not sure :)

Comment: @Alan, yes on 4. 12 is close. Note what was circled in its first sketch. 9, no.

Comment: @msh210 So would 12 be 'Rastafarian' (or just 'Rasta') then?

Comment: Yeah, the former was my intent.

Comment: 9 seem to me to be someone talking about the weather/ rain clouds. I do not know an applicable O for that though.

Comment: @msh210 Aftermath: what was the intended solution for 9?

Comment: @1357924680a I'm still hoping someone will find it. Hint: The three similar-looking things are meant to be automobiles.

Comment: @msh210 Could it be an OVERPASS or an OFF-RAMP?  (the squiggles are the roads crossing over/under each other)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain not my intention, I'm afraid.